# curlpp c++ disable printing

Tags: c++, api, console, curlpp

sorry if this is a silly question, but I can't seem to get rid of the console output when making a request using cURLpp. I am programming a bot so I need to read data from the console in real time and it is very difficult with all this.

I have tried several ways I have read the documentation(https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp/blob/master/doc/guide.pdf) I have tried examples but I can't seem to get rid of the output

This is an example of my code:

```
std::string function() {
try
{
    curlpp::Cleanup cleaner;
    curlpp::Easy request;

    request.setOpt(curlpp::options::Url("url"));
    
    request.setOpt(curlpp::options::Verbose(true));

    std::ostringstream response;
    request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::WriteStream(&response));

    request.perform();
    return response.str();

}
catch (curlpp::LogicError& e) {
    std::cout << "ERROR Logic" << std::endl;
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return e.what();
}
catch (curlpp::RuntimeError& e) {
    std::cout << "ERROR runtime" << std::endl;
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return e.what();
}
```

}

And always get something like this

...

- schannel: decrypted data added: 4055
- schannel: decrypted cached: offset 4055 length 16581
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 17408
- schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 4055 length 16581
- schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
- schannel: decrypted data returned 4055
- schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 16581
- STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0xa625e8; line 2251 (connection #0)
- multi_done

...

Please help with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: `request.setOpt(curlpp::options::Verbose(true))` line looks suspicious. I guess it turns on the trace output you see.

Comment: So long looking in the wrong place ... thanks